# Why does a car which decelerates slowly on a icy road not slip but a car which decelerates quickly does?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction

Why is it that braking slowly on an icy road is safer than braking quickly. Intuitively it makes sense but what is the logic?

Answer (score 1):

Due to static friction between the tire and the road, if the force is higher than some threshold, the tires will slip. In this case, a larger deceleration implies a larger force. In order to ensure that you don't exceed the threshold for rolling friction, you want to keep the deceleration force as small as possible while still stopping the car in the allotted distance.

Comment: _Like_ static friction? or _is_ static friction? If the tire grips the surface at any given instant, does the name for that phenomenon have to change just because a moment later a different part of the tire is gripping a different part of the surface?

Comment: The name changes because different parts of the object are in contact with the surface at any given time, rather than a *static* situation, where everything is fixed.

Comment: Rolling friction is generally the term used for [rolling resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_resistance), not for the friction between the car tires and the road.  Rolling friction isn't much like static friction at all.  The friction between perfectly rolling tires and the road is static (as Solomon's comment points out; we do actually call this static friction, there's no relative movement between the two surfaces parallel to them).  The last sentence is misleading.  You obviously don't want the deceleration force as small as possible, or else you wouldn't be stopping.

Comment: @JMac You are right, I misused terminology. But I think it is obvious that my last sentence is dealing with the constraint of *actually stopping within an allotted distance*.

Comment: @Danny But you want the deceleration as _large_ as possible to do this, not as small as possible.  There's an _upper limit_ which exceeding will make the deceleration worse, but that's not the same thing as saying you want to make deceleration force as small as possible... at all.

Comment: @JMac For a driver that does not have an accelerometer on their dashboard, that person would want to break as non-abruptly as possible when slowing down. This is because you can't be sure exactly when you will cross the skid threshold. If you had an accelerometer on your dash, I would say yes, go ahead and break as fast as you want without crossing the skid threshold (provided you don't give your passengers whiplash).

Comment: @Danny It's still the _complete opposite_ of "keep the deceleration force as small as possible".  You literally want to keep the deceleration force as large as possible, the specifics of the situation will just affect how you achieve that.  Your answer says the opposite of the truth and is misleading.   Braking abruptly and applying the maximum deceleration force are completely different things in this situation.  That is really the core of the issue, and the answer seems to gloss right over it.

Comment: @JMac We seem to be talking past each other. Maybe this is a misunderstanding of signs and magnitudes.

Comment: @Danny I'm interpreting "decelerating" as "the car losing velocity" or "acceleration opposite the direction of motion".  I don't see how else it could be used in reference to a braking car.  If you mean something else, I suggest clarifying.  Regardless, if I take your words at face value, it suggests the best way to brake on ice is to not apply the brakes at all, because that would be "keeping the deceleration force as small as possible".

Comment: @JMac This is a simple issue of constrained optimization. If you are respecting the constraint that you *have to stop within an allotted distance*, then no, not breaking at all is not an optimum solution to keeping the deceleration force as small as possible when stopping. I still think that it is obvious enough that the goal is still to *stop the car within an allotted time* when I recommend minimizing deceleration. The solution is also simple: constant deceleration.

Comment: @Danny Constant deceleration =/= minimizing deceleration.  I agree that not stopping at all is not a viable solution, but your answer doesn't remotely address that, or discuss the assumed constraints (which are not mentioned in the problem).  The way I see it, the goal is to stop the car in the minimal distance possible, while maintaining control and without harming the passengers.  If you're going to say you need to make the force as small as possible, but you don't actually mean minimize it in all respects, you should _elaborate_.  This answer could easily be improved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97443/discussion-between-danny-and-jmac).

Answer (score 0):

It is the contact between your tires and the road which ultimately slows down (and speeds up) your car, based on how your tires are interacting with the road.  Friction force depends on normal force, coefficient of friction, and whether there is relative movement between the two surfaces.

When there is no relative movement between the surfaces, the friction is static, and has a higher coefficient of friction compared to kinetic friction.  This allows for more friction with the same weight.  Car tires which are not skidding have static friction between the tire and the road, because the two surfaces in contact do not have any movement parallel to each other while in contact.  When your car is skidding, it is kinetic friction which affects your movement on the road instead.

Since the coefficient of kinetic friction is less than the coefficient of static friction, the force between the car and the road is reduced when the car begins to skid.  Since this friction is ultimately responsible for slowing down the car, you want the friction to be able to keep up with the torque on the wheels without exceeding the maximum static friction, which causes skidding.

If you try to brake too quickly, you apply more torque than the static friction is able to account for, the tires begin to skid, and the friction force which slows you down and controls your vehicle is decreased.  This causes braking to take longer, and also may cause the car to lose control.

Optimal braking on an icy road involves applying the maximum force on the brakes *without* causing the tires to skid.  On modern cars, this can be felt through the [ABS (anti-lock braking system)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-lock_braking_system). When you slam the brakes with an ABS, especially in icy conditions, the brakes don't fully activate.  Instead the system periodically "pumps" the brakes to try to avoid any skidding (if you've ever tried to slam your brakes on ice with an ABS, you can notice this and it feels weird).  It's worth noting that manually adjusting your brake strength can often give better results than relying on ABS in icy conditions, so easing onto the brakes instead of slamming them and relying on ABS is still advised.

Slamming the brakes often applies too much torque and overcomes the static friction threshold, leading to the unwanted skidding.  Applying just enough brakes to meet the static friction threshold is the best way to stop quickly and safely, and in icy conditions this generally requires easing onto the brakes.